# PayPal Checkout API with PHP - Sending and retrieving additional data safely

Tags: php, api, paypal

I am learning to use the new API version of Paypal, and I have some doubts.

> Note: I've tried this on https://www.sandbox.paypal.com and it works,
>   I have not done the tests on Live.

## onApprove:

I need to send additional personalized data to Paypal, and once the user makes the payment, I return to a URL on my server, and then retrieve the data I sent.

Paypal uses **fetch()** to do to specify the URL and a Json object called headers, there I am adding the additional value called *user_ID* that I need to recover.

I am using the PHP function **getallheaders()**, to retrieve *user_ID*, which I have specified.

**My questions are:**

1. Is this a correct way to send personalized data to PayPal and then be recovered?
2. It is safe to use **getallheaders()**, I understand that the headers can be modified before being sent, is there any possibility that these can be altered?
3. Using **$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']**, to detect that the referred website is from Paypal, is this still safe or difficult to break?
4. Would this be a secure way to integrate Paypal Checkout?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>

<body>


    <input type="text" id="price" value="100.00">
  <input type="hidden" id="user_id" value="15">

    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=HERE_CLIENT_ID&currency=USD"></script>

    <script>
    paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: document.getElementById("price").value
          }
        }]
      });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
        // Call your server to save the transaction
        return fetch('https://my-domain.com/payment-from-paypal.php', {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            orderID: data.orderID,
            user_ID: document.getElementById("user_id").value
          })
        });
      });
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: No, I don’t think this is the way this should be done. Non-standard header names should begin with `x-` for starters; but I would dispute whether this info belongs into a request header in the first place. _“Paypal uses fetch()”_ - more precise, _you_ are using fetch here, in your own client-side JavaScript code. Why are you not just putting this additional value into the JSON data you are sending as the request body in that place?

Comment: Then you recommend that I use them in body: JSON.stringify ({}), updated code, and then in the Backend we should use file_get_contents ('php://input'), to obtain that data? If you can help us with an example, and good practices please.

Comment: You seem to know how this basically works already … so try something, and report back if you run into problems.